# why is scaled html5 video on canvas blurry & wrong size?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-canvas, html5-video

In chrome, I load in a html5 video and grab a frame.
Then I put that frame into a canvas element.
Then I scale both elements to make them smaller.
When the freeze-framed video and the canvas overlaid, the canvas is slightly larger by about 1 pixel (and fuzzier).
What am I doing wrong?

https://codepen.io/jedierikb/pen/ooEqLy

```
var $v = document.getElementById('video');
var $c = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = $c.getContext('2d');

var cvsVis = true;

$v.addEventListener( 'seeked', function() {

    var vbr = $v.getBoundingClientRect();
    $c.style.width = vbr.width + 'px';
    $c.style.height = vbr.height + 'px';
    $c.width = vbr.width;
    $c.height = vbr.height;
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, vbr.width, vbr.height);

    TweenMax.set( [$v,$c], {
      scale: .75
    });


    var $t = document.getElementById('toggle');
    $t.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
      cvsVis = !cvsVis;
      $c.style.display = cvsVis ? 'block' : 'none';
    });

});
$v.currentTime = 30;
$v.pause();
```

Comment: webkit has fancy algo to resize <img> tags, <video> doesn't have the same process, so it looks worse when re-sized. there's not a lot you can do about it. try adjusting the alias modes on canvas css

Comment: Not exactly sure why, but what seems to happen is that both get a final computed width of `640.5px`. Chrome can't achieve it so antialiasing will kick in. Canvas will try to reach `641px`, by ceiling this value, while video will try to floor this value. Note that div elements seem to foolow the same rules as canvas.